# Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Memory allocation failed

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, phpexcel

Facing an issue in excel sheet & CSV reader with large quantities of records in Codeignitor.

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: simplexml_load_string(): Memory allocation failed : growing buffer
Filename: Reader/Excel2007.php
Line Number: 645
Backtrace:
File: \application\third_party\PHPExcel\Reader\Excel2007.php
Line: 645
Function: simplexml_load_string
File: \application\controllers\admin\Csv.php
Line: 56
Function: load
File: \index.php
Line: 322
Function: require_once
```

Comment: Even if the error message was formatted intelligibly (insert a line `> \`\`\`` before and after): who is going to guess  the cause with no source code shown?

Answer (score 0):

The first option is to increase memory for php with the setting in the file php.ini.

```
memory_limit = 256M
```

The number can be lower and different but should be at least higher then it's now, but surely it can be higher than 256M too.
After the change perhaps the sever has to be restarted (depends on some things).

If that doesn't help, then it's worth it to look at the application and even the CSV-file.
Basic problem concerning most frameworks is that data are collected, hold in memory, parsed and then the results are shown or written in the database if applying.
Programs for big data have somehow to chunk the data and that also can mean just to streamline and processing step by step (like a video or soundfile).
As `XML`is no stream-format but requires a fully parsed structure before it's processed usually the hint might look a bit useless. But perhaps there are a few things you could do to reduce the data-amount to be processed at once:

- If `simplexml` is used to process several files at once it should be easy just to reduce the amount of files.
- if the `XML`-file(s) are just too large you've to produce smaller files. It's also possible to split files but a little bit knowledge about `XML` is required for it.

In general it's possible that small tweaks at the implementation in `CodeIgniter` could solve the problem already, but as that one is unknown here we can only guess about it.

Answer (score 0):

To increase PHP memory limit setting, edit your PHP.ini file. Simply increase the default value (example: Maximum amount of memory a script may consume = 128MB) of the PHP memory limit line in php.ini.

```
memory_limit = 256M
```

Alternatively you can edit your .htaccess file.

```
php_value memory_limit 256M
```

**Note:** If you don’t have access to these files or lack the experience to make this change, you can contact your web host and ask them to increase your PHP memory limit.