# Laravel 7 Maatwebsite Excel:import simplexml_load_string(): Memory allocation failed : building node

Tags: php, excel, laravel, maatwebsite-excel

I uploaded my application to the VPS server and weird stuff started to build: namely when importing an xlsx file weighing 37 megabytes (500k lines). The server returns something like this:

simplexml_load_string(): Memory allocation failed : building node Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions::handleError vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Reader/Xlsx.php:144

Locally on windows xampp this file normally passes through. Memory_limit on the server I set the same as on windows. Any advice?

Comment: See the following post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59052734/warning-simplexml-load-string-memory-allocation-failed

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert large xlsx file to csv without using phpExcel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20113261/convert-large-xlsx-file-to-csv-without-using-phpexcel)